# Django, assign many-to-many relation between two tables with predefined values in both tables

Tags: django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Currently, I an using django rest framework. I want to replicate django's default role-permission selection in rest api form.
I have listed auth_group with permission inside it. 
Problem is: Permission and group is already fetched in database. I only want to create link between group and permission using django's default tables. (I want to assign permission to group.)

Here are my serializers.

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:        
        model = Permission        
        fields = (
            'pk', 
            'codename',
            'name'
        )      
        read_only_fields = ('pk',)

class UserGroupSerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:        
        model = Group        
        fields = (
            'pk', 
            'name',
            'permissions'
        )      
        read_only_fields = ('pk',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        """
        permission_data = validated_data.pop('permissions')
        group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for permission in permission_data:
            permissionNow = Permission.objects.get(name='view_profile')
            group.permissions.add(permissionNow)
        return group
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    # retrive all users or create a user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        groups = Group.objects.all()
        serializer = UserGroupSerializer(groups, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserGroupSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

currently, it gives

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'permissions'.
```

And I don't want to create permission because it is already available in DB.
Only thing I want is to store link between group and permission. (assign existing permissions to existing groups).
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this following

```
 permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True)
```

to

```
 permissions = PermissionSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
```

#### update

In django-restframework-serializer cycle there are certain things perfrom sequentially. As for your case my assumption was how to pass the permissions field validation check. whenever you declare another serializer which in `PermissionSerializer` in this which expect following field should pass the validation of that serializer, where `codename` and `name` is required and certainly not passing them thats why you are getting that error. If we assign that field as read_only following checking will by-pass. I hope you will get permissions in validated_data, if it is not there, you can get from `self.context['request']data.get('permissions')` in your overwriten `create` method.

### Edit

UserGroupSerializer should go like this

```
class UserGroupSerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:        
        model = Group        
        fields = (
            'pk', 
            'name',
            'permissions'
        )      
        read_only_fields = ('pk',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Overriding the default create method of the Model serializer.
        """
        permission_data = self.context['request'].data.get('permissions')
        group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for permission in permission_data:
            permissionNow = Permission.objects.get(name='view_profile')
            group.permissions.add(permissionNow)
        return group
```

And also in views

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserGroupSerializer(data = request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How to pass context-data to serializer, relevant reading [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

Comment: But when I changed to permissions=PermissionSerizliser(read_only=True, many=True)
How can I pass permission's object/id to create relation between group and permission? Because, values under permissions index is not accepted if I make read_only=True

Comment: it doesnot work. self.context.request.data.get('permissions) cannot be used.

Comment: can you please add your view function in question @amit

Comment: ok, you are manually called that, i thought you are using, any `Viewset` or `Mixins` class. For this you need to manually passed the context i am afraid. changed `UserGroupSerializer(data = request.data)` to `UserGroupSerializer(data = request.data,  context={'request': request} )`

Comment: @amit can you please update your code, so that it will be easier to get the problem.

Comment: @amit i just edited my answer. can you please check now.